# Can this code be made more Pythonic? Loops

Tags: python, while-loop

So I am writing some code to roll three fudge dice (six sided dice with sides of -1,-1,0,0,+1,+1). If the three dice together roll a total of -3, I have a function that then rolls a single fudge dice over and over again, subtacting 1 from the total for each -1 that get's rolled and quiting if something other than a -1 is rolled - in this way I get an "explosion down" making totals less than -3 possible, though increasingly less likely.

My explode down function is this:

```
def explodedown():
  curval = -3
  while 1:
    newroll = rolldie()
    if newroll != -1:
      break
    else:
      curval = curval-1
  return curval;
```

That seems to work well enough, but I almost feel that if I wanted to write this even more simply, there should be some way to write the loop more like:

```
while newroll == -1
  newroll = rolldie()
  curval = curval-1
```

And then the loop would naturally break without needing an if statement. Problem is newroll does not exist until we get inside the loop, so I don't think that will work. Maybe if I added another statement before the loop starts like:

```
newroll = rolldie()
while newroll == -1
  newroll = rolldie()
  curval = curval-1
```

But it seems un-pythonic to have the newroll line there twice.

Thoughts? is there a way to simplify and make more readable my explode down function?

Comment: initializing a value so that you can use it in the `while` statement is not un-Pythonic. It's standard practice. (`curval = curval-1` -> `curval -= 1`)

Comment: As a sidenote, I notice you have `while 1`. I'm not sure what you're achieving by doing this, but this is the same as `while True` which, although it isn't more or less pythonic, is more readable

Comment: Ev. Kouris: I need the value to start at -3 because that indicates that the original roll before we entered this function was three -1's. Although I guess I could have saved a line, omitted the curval = -3, and simply altered the return line to say return curval-3, although I think that might be less readable.

mangoHero: excellent and valid point. Moot however due to Jonas' excellent solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
while rolldie() == -1:
    curval -= 1
```

Comment: OMG, I feel so  stupid for not seeing that, SO ELEGANT! Thank you.

Comment: It made me wait 2 minutes to do that, but I have now done so - again, thanks.